# How do you say you know OF something?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique

Saying you know *of* something means that you only have heard a little about it. You’ll most commonly hear it like this:

> Do you know Terry?
>
> I know *of* him.

This means you might have heard about Terry or have seen him but haven’t really met him or talked to him.

How do you translate this phrasing into French?

Comment: « j'en ai entendu parler », where I come from.

Answer (score 6):

Besides  "Je sais qui c’est." and "Je vois qui c’est." in this [answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/36928/17649), the following locutions may apply as they express various degrees of acquaintance;

- (Je le connais) de vue.
- On se dit bonjour.
- Par ouï-dire.
- De ouï-dire. (*rare*)
- J'ai entendu parler de lui.
- (Je (ne) le connais) Pas vraiment.
- (Je (ne) le connais) Pas trop bien.
- (Je le connais) Comme ci comme ça.
- (Je le connais) Comme ça.
- (Je (ne) le connais) Pas intimement.

Comment: L'orthographe correcte est *ouï-dire* (cf . https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ou%C3%AF-dire).

Answer (score 5):

I would say "Je sais qui c’est." (I know who he is.) or "Je vois qui c’est." (I see who he is).

Answer (score 2):

This dialog would be close:

> — Tu connais Terry ?
>
> — Un peu.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the translation for those  two lines, this should be it :

> Tu connais Terry?

"Oui je le connais" or "Je sais qui il est"

Comment: *« Je sais de lui. » is just not French.

Comment: I just translated the phase mentioned above.am really sorry if my answer wasn't good enough

Comment: Yeah i agree i might have misunderstood the question here instead of that it could have "Un peu" or "je sais qui il est" or "Oui je le connais_